# Delete key is printing "^?" instead of deleting

Tags: ssh

I am ssh-ing into a server and when I am editing files, the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key does not delete; instead it prints "^?"

How can I fix this so that the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key actually deletes the character before the cursor?

Comment: This should be on another SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the shell:

```
$ stty erase ^V<delete key>
```

where ^V is control-V, followed by the key you wish to use as the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.  Then, of course, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Control-V puts the next character typed actually into the shell command instead of making it have whatever effect it may normally have.